# Por quê o atributo da classe não é modificada?

Tags: python, python-3.x, processo

Preciso somente enviar um comando de um processo para o outro, mas queria entender por que ao modificar a variável dentro de uma função, ela não aparece em outra função.

```
from  multiprocessing import Process
import time

ComandoSerial = 0

class teste():

    var = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.var2 = 0

    def funcao(self):
        self.__class__.var = 1
        self.var2 = 1

    def funcao2(self):
        self.__class__.var = 2
        self.var2 = 2

    def funcao3(self):
        self.__class__.var = 3
        self.var2 = 3

    def retorna(self):
        return  self.__class__.var

    def retorna2(self):
        return self.var2


test = teste()

def Teste1():
    test.funcao3()

def Teste2():
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print("VALOR = ", test.retorna())


p  = Process(target= Teste1)
p1 = Process(target= Teste2)


def main():
    p.start()
    p1.start()
    p.join()
    p1.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

O problema é que coloco o valor 3, mas ao ler sempre retorna 0.

Comment: O problema básico é que está utilizando processos e as variáveis não são compartilhadas entre si. Você precisa compartilhar este objeto de alguma forma. Veja sobre isso na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

Comment: É possível passar uma instância de classe para um processo ?

Comment: Precisava de uma "comunicação" diferente da documentação. Preciso que seja conforme o código acima. Naquela ideia de modificar um valor em um processo e ler em outro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se esta pergunta é uma extensão da anterior, sobre comunicação entre processos, você deveria ter seguido as dicas que lhe foram dadas nela. Como comentei, as variáveis não são compartilhadas entre processos e, desta forma, em cada processo haverá uma instância diferente; por isso que as alterações feitas em um processo não são refletidas nos outros (se você der um `print` dentro do método `__init__` verá que ele é chamado 3 vezes: uma no processo principal e outras duas nos processos criados manualmente).

Para comunicar os dois processos, você pode utilizar o `multiprocessing.Pipe`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

class Foo:
    # Classe de teste, não tente isso em casa
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

def receiver(stream):
    obj = stream.recv()
    obj.value = 2
    stream.send(obj)
    stream.close()

def sender(stream):
    obj = Foo()
    print("Antes:", obj.value)
    stream.send(obj)
    obj = stream.recv()
    print("Depois:", obj.value)
    stream.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent, child = Pipe()

    p1 = Process(target=receiver, args=(child,))
    p2 = Process(target=sender, args=(parent,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

No processo 2, executando a função `sender`, eu crio um novo objeto `Foo` e exibo o valor inicial 0; após, envio-o através da *pipe* para o outro processo; no processo 1, executando `receiver`, eu leio da *pipe* o objeto, altero o valor do atributo para 2 e retorno-o via *pipe*; de volta no processo 2, eu leio a resposta do processo 1 e exibo novamente o valor do atributo, que estará modificado.